# Property Names as Lambda Expression in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Updating question to be more clear on what i am trying to do here.

What i am really trying to do here is use Z.EntityFramework.Extensions to BulkMerge some data into database. Specifically i am trying to create instructions in options.ColumnInputExpression which takes the Expression i mentioned above. You can see an example here on dotnetfiddle.net/lwF8DZ

I have been working on this for few days now and can't seem to make any progress. Here is what i have.

Lets say i have Customer class.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

And using something like this i can create a simple expression to target fields "Description" and "IsActive"

```
Expression<Func<Customer, object>> fieldsToUse = c => new { c.Description, c.IsActive };
```

This expression is exactly what i want but i must not hardcore it, instead i have to use a List such as this:

```
List<string> fld = new List<string>();
fld.Add("Description");
fld.Add("IsActive");
```

So far i have managed to use this:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, object>> GetExpression<T>(string propName)
{
    var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "c");
    var property = Expression.Property(arg, propName);
    var conversion = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));
    var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(conversion , new ParameterExpression[] { arg });
    return exp;
}
```

which i can call like this:

```
var exp = GetExpression<Customer>("IsActive");
```

But this only gives me following:

```
Expression<Func<Customer, object>> sample = c => c.IsActive;
```

How can i create the initial expression using what i have?

```
Expression<Func<Customer, object>> sample = c => new { c.Description, c.IsActive };
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `new { c.Description, c.IsActive }` is a tricky one - because that is a compiler-generated type with properties `Description` and `IsActive`. You can't do that *just* in an expression - you'd also need to dynamically generate a `Type` via `TypeBuilder` which is a *lot* of work - or use a different representation of the multiple properties; basically: this kind of projection isn't a good fit for dynamic lambdas

Comment: What you've got at the moment is `Expression<Func<Customer, object>> sample = c => c.IsActive`, not `Expression<Func<Customer, object>> sample= c => new { c.IsActive };`. You're missing the whole step to create the anonymous object

Comment: What do you use the anonymous object for?

Comment: It's a lot easier to create a value tuple, why don't you use that instead?

Comment: Or just pass multiple expressions to your final function and loop over them. I guess it depends what you are actually doing with them

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for the replies. What i am really trying to do here is use Z.EntityFramework.Extensions to BulkMerge some data into database. Specifically i am trying to create instructions in options.ColumnInputExpression which takes the Expression i mentioned above. You can see an example here on https://dotnetfiddle.net/lwF8DZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to do what you're doing to solve the problem you're trying to solve. The bulk insert options in `Z.EntityFramework.Extensions` includes a `ColumnInputNames` property you can use instead of providing an expression. The expression syntax is probably just a convenience method that parses the expression you give it and converts it into a list of property names anyway.

```
context.BulkInsert(list, options => 
    options.ColumnInputNames = new List<string>{ "Name", "IsActive" });
```

Or, given your dynamically-generated `fld` list:

```
context.BulkInsert(list, options => options.ColumnInputNames = fld);
```